# SwiftUI Problem GeometryReader with Zstack

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to create my own PhoneTextField in and I have found a tutorial in [here](https://betterprogramming.pub/create-phone-number-textfield-with-country-codes-and-flags-in-swiftui-fa3ad981c5f6) it's working fine if don't call it inside ZStack let's see the code example as below

countryCode View

```
struct CountryCodes: View {
    @Binding var countryCode : String
    @Binding var countryFlag : String
    @Binding var y : CGFloat

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            List(self.countryDictionary.sorted(by: <), id: \.key) { key , value in
                HStack {
                    Text("\(self.flag(country: key))")
                    Text("\(self.countryName(countryCode: key) ?? key)")
                    Spacer()
                    Text("+\(value)").foregroundColor(.secondary)
                }.background(Color.white)
                .font(.system(size: 20))
                .onTapGesture {
                    self.countryCode = value
                    self.countryFlag = self.flag(country: key)
                    withAnimation(.spring()) {
                        self.y = 350
                    }
                }
            }
            .padding(.bottom)
            .frame(width: geo.size.width, height: 500)
            .position(x: geo.frame(in: .global).midX, y: geo.frame(in: .global).maxY - -200)
            
            
        }
    }
    let countryDictionary  = ["AF":"93","AL":"355","DZ":"213","US":"1",
                              "AD":"376","AO":"244","AI":"1","AG":"1","AR":"54",
                              "AM":"374","AW":"297","AU":"61","AT":"43","AZ":"994",
                              "BS":"1","BH":"973","BD":"880","BB":"1","BY":"375",
                              "BE":"32","BZ":"501","BJ":"229","BM":"1","BT":"975",
                              "BA":"387","BW":"267","BR":"55","IO":"246","BG":"359",
                              "BF":"226","BI":"257","KH":"855","CM":"237","CA":"1",
                              "CV":"238","KY":"345","CF":"236","TD":"235","CL":"56","CN":"86",
                              "CX":"61","CO":"57","KM":"269","CG":"242","CK":"682","CR":"506",
                              "HR":"385","CU":"53","CY":"537","CZ":"420","DK":"45","DJ":"253",
                              "DM":"1","DO":"1","EC":"593","EG":"20","SV":"503","GQ":"240",
                              "ER":"291","EE":"372","ET":"251","FO":"298","FJ":"679","FI":"358",
                              "FR":"33","GF":"594","PF":"689","GA":"241","GM":"220","GE":"995",
                              "DE":"49","GH":"233","GI":"350","GR":"30","GL":"299","GD":"1",
                              "GP":"590","GU":"1","GT":"502","GN":"224","GW":"245","GY":"595","HT":"509",
                              "HN":"504","HU":"36","IS":"354","IN":"91","ID":"62","IQ":"964",
                              "IE":"353","IL":"972","IT":"39","JM":"1","JP":"81","JO":"962",
                              "KZ":"77","KE":"254","KI":"686","KW":"965","KG":"996","LV":"371",
                              "LB":"961","LS":"266","LR":"231","LI":"423","LT":"370","LU":"352",
                              "MG":"261","MW":"265","MY":"60","MV":"960","ML":"223",
                              "MT":"356","MH":"692","MQ":"596","MR":"222","MU":"230","YT":"262",
                              "MX":"52","MC":"377","MN":"976", "ME":"382","MS":"1","MA":"212",
                              "MM":"95","NA":"264","NR":"674","NP":"977","NL":"31","NC":"687",
                              "NZ":"64","NI":"505","NE":"227","NG":"234","NU":"683",
                              "NF":"672","MP":"1","NO":"47","OM":"968","PK":"92","PW":"680",
                              "PA":"507","PG":"675","PY":"595","PE":"51","PH":"63","PL":"48",
                              "PT":"351","PR":"1","QA":"974","RO":"40","RW":"250","WS":"685",
                              "SM":"378","SA":"966","SN":"221","RS":"381","SC":"248",
                              "SL":"232","SG":"65","SK":"421","SI":"386","SB":"677",
                              "ZA":"27","GS":"500","ES":"34","LK":"94","SD":"249","SR":"597",
                              "SZ":"268","SE":"46","CH":"41","TJ":"992","TH":"66","TG":"228",
                              "TK":"690","TO":"676","TT":"1","TN":"216","TR":"90",
                              "TM":"993","TC":"1","TV":"688","UG":"256","UA":"380",
                              "AE":"971","GB":"44","AS":"1","UY":"598","UZ":"998",
                              "VU":"678","WF":"681","YE":"967","ZM":"260",
                              "ZW":"263","BO":"591","BN":"673","CC":"61",
                              "CD":"243","CI":"225","FK":"500","GG":"44",
                              "VA":"379","HK":"852","IR":"98","IM":"44",
                              "JE":"44","KP":"850","KR":"82","LA":"856",
                              "LY":"218","MO":"853","MK":"389","FM":"691",
                              "MD":"373","MZ":"258","PS":"970","PN":"872",
                              "RE":"262","RU":"7","BL":"590","SH":"290","KN":"1",
                              "LC":"1","MF":"590","PM":"508","VC":"1","ST":"239",
                              "SO":"252","SJ":"47","SY":"963","TW":"886","TZ":"255",
                              "TL":"670","VE":"58","VN":"84","VG":"284","VI":"340"]
    
    func countryName(countryCode: String) -> String? {
        let current = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
        return current.localizedString(forRegionCode: countryCode)
    }
    
    
    
    func flag(country:String) -> String {
        let base : UInt32 = 127397
        var flag = ""
        for v in country.unicodeScalars {
            flag.unicodeScalars.append(UnicodeScalar(base + v.value)!)
        }
        return flag
    }
    
    
}
```

RegistrationView

```
    //
    //  RegisterView.swift
    //  Instagram
    //
    //  Created by Admin on 4/4/21.
    //

    import SwiftUI
    import Combine

    struct RegistrationView: View {
        @State var isEditing: Bool = false
        // navigate to verification view
        @State private var selection: String? = nil

        @State private var email:String = ""
        @State private var phone:String = ""
        @State private var fullname = ""
        @State private var username = ""
        @State private var password = ""
        @State private var selectedImage:UIImage?
        @State private var image:Image?
        @Environment(\.presentationMode) var mode
        @State var imagePickerPresented = false
        @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: AuthViewModel
        @State var isVerification = false
        
        @State var phoneNumber = ""
        @State var y : CGFloat = 350
        @State var countryCode = ""
        @State var countryFlag = ""
        
        @State var isInputPhoneNumber = true
        @State var isInputEmail = false
        @State var tempData = DataTempo()
        @State var isShowSignInButton = true
//        var successClosure: (Bool) -> Void {
//            
//        }

        @EnvironmentObject  var mobileVerificationViewModel: MobileVerificationNvm
        var body: some View {
            ZStack {
                LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.purple, Color("PrimaryColor")]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
                VStack{
                        //                    Spacer()
                        VStack(spacing:20){
                            VStack(alignment:.leading){
                                Text("Sign Up")
                                    .font(.largeTitle)
                                    .bold()
                                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                                
                            }.padding(.horizontal,32).frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, alignment: .leading)
                            
                            Toggle( isInputEmail ? "Use Email" : "Use Phone Number", isOn: $isInputEmail)
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                                .toggleStyle(SwitchToggleStyle(tint: Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.5568627715, green: 0.3529411852, blue: 0.9686274529, alpha: 1))))
                                .padding(.horizontal,32)
                            
                            
                            if isInputEmail == true {
                                
                                CustomTextField(text: $email, placeholder: Text("Email"), imageName: "envelope")
                                    .padding()
                                    .background(Color(.init(white: 1, alpha: 0.15)))
                                    .cornerRadius(10)
                                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                                    .padding(.horizontal,32)
                                    .onChange(of: email) {
                                        // self.autocomplete($0) // like this
                                        if  viewModel.isValidEmail(testStr: $0){
                                            print("email")
                                            //phone number
                                        }
                                    }
                                
                            }
                            if isInputEmail == false{
                                
                              
                                    ZStack(alignment:.center) {
                                        HStack (spacing: 0) {
                                            Text(countryCode.isEmpty ? " +66" : "\(countryFlag) +\(countryCode)")
                                                .frame(width: 100, height: 50)
                                                //                                            .background(Color.secondary.opacity(0.2))
                                                .background(Color(.init(white: 1, alpha: 0.15)))
                                                .cornerRadius(10)
                                                //                                            .foregroundColor(countryCode.isEmpty ? .secondary : .black)
                                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                                                .onTapGesture {
                                                    isShowSignInButton = false
                                                    withAnimation (.spring()) {
                                                        self.y = 0
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            TextField("Phone Number", text: $phone)
                                                
                                                .onChange(of: phone) { newValue  in
                                                    if !phone.isEmpty {
                                                        self.isShowSignInButton = true
                                                        if  viewModel.validatePhoneNumber(value:newValue){
                                                            print("phone")
                                                            //phone number
                                                            self.isInputPhoneNumber = true
                                                            self.isInputEmail = false
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                    else{
                                                        self.isShowSignInButton = false
                                                    }
                                                }
                                                .frame(width: 250, height: 50)
                                                .keyboardType(.phonePad)
                                                .background(Color(.init(white: 1, alpha: 0.15)))
                                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                                        }
                                        
                                        
                                        CountryCodes(countryCode: $countryCode, countryFlag: $countryFlag, y: $y)
                                         
                                            .offset(y: y)
                                        
                                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10).stroke()
                                            .frame(width: 350, height: 50)
                                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                                    }   .zIndex(1).frame( height: 50, alignment: .center)
                                    
                                
                                
                            }
                            
                            CustomTextField(text: $username, placeholder: Text("Username"), imageName: "person")
                                .padding()
                                .background(Color(.init(white: 1, alpha: 0.15)))
                                .cornerRadius(10)
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                                .padding(.horizontal,32)
                            CustomTextField(text: $fullname, placeholder: Text("Full Name"), imageName: "person")
                                .padding()
                                .background(Color(.init(white: 1, alpha: 0.15)))
                                .cornerRadius(10)
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                                .padding(.horizontal,32)
                            CustomSecureField(text: $password, placeholder: Text("Password"))
                                .padding()
                                .background(Color(.init(white: 1, alpha: 0.15)))
                                .cornerRadius(10)
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                                .padding(.horizontal,32)
                        }
                        .alert(isPresented: $isInputPhoneNumber, content: {
                            Alert(title: Text("Message"), message: Text("you're using phone number to register"), dismissButton: .default(Text("Bye alert!"), action: {
                                isInputPhoneNumber = true
                            }))
                        })
                        
                        
                        .alert(isPresented: mobileVerificationViewModel.alertBinding) {
                            Alert(title: Text(mobileVerificationViewModel.errorMessage ?? "(unknown)"), message: nil, dismissButton: .cancel())
                        }
                        HStack{
                            Spacer()
                            Button(action: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/{}/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/, label: {
                                Text("Forgot Password")
                            })
                            .font(.system(size: 13, weight: .semibold))
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .padding(.top)
                            .padding(.trailing,28)
                        }
                    ZStack{
                        NavigationLink(destination:VerificationView { (pin, successClosure) in
                            print(pin)
                            
                            mobileVerificationViewModel.codeVerification(phoneNumber: isInputEmail ? tempData.email : tempData.phone, pinCode: pin, email: email, password: password, fullname: fullname, username: username)
                            
                            //navigation back
                            self.mode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                            // print(successClosure)
                        }, tag: "verification", selection: $selection) { EmptyView() }
                 
                        Button(action: {
                            self.selection = "verification"
                            var phoneWithCountryCode = ""
                            
//                            if countryCode == "" {
//                                phoneWithCountryCode = "+66\(phone)"
//                            }
//                            if countryCode != ""{
//                                phoneWithCountryCode = "+\(countryCode)\(phone)"
//                            }
//
//                            //                        "+\(countryCode == "" ? "66" : countryCode + phone)"
//                            if (!email.isEmpty || !phone.isEmpty) && !password.isEmpty{
//
//                                if isInputEmail {
//                                    MobileVerificationNvm.shared.sendVerification(phoneNumber:email)
//                                    isVerification = true
//                                    tempData.email = email
//                                }
//
//                                else{
//                                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
//                                        //                                print("phone:\(phoneWithCountryCode)")
//                                        MobileVerificationNvm.shared.sendVerification(phoneNumber: phoneWithCountryCode)
//                                        isVerification = true
//                                        tempData.phone = phone
//                                    }
//
//                                }
//
//                            }
                            //                    viewModel.register(withEmail: email, password: password,image: selectedImage,fullname: fullname,username: username)
                        }, label: {
                            Text("Sign Up")
                        }).zIndex(0)
                        //                    Spacer()
                    }
                    .font(.headline)
                    .frame(width: 360, height: 50)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .background(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.5568627715, green: 0.3529411852, blue: 0.9686274529, alpha: 1)))
                    //                .clipShape(Capsule())
                    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16, style: .continuous))
                    .padding()
                
                    .alert(isPresented: $isInputEmail, content: {
                        Alert(title: Text("Message"), message: Text("Now! you're using Email to register but you also register with email just swtich on togle button"), dismissButton: .default(Text("Bye alert!"), action: {
                            isInputEmail = true
                        }))
                    })
                    
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        mode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                        //                        isVerification = true
                    }, label: {
                        Text("Already have an account? ")
                            .font(.system(size: 14))
                            + Text("Sign In")
                            .font(.system(size: 14, weight: .bold))
                    })
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding(.bottom,32)
                    
                    }
                 
                }
                .ignoresSafeArea()
                
            }
        
        }



    extension RegistrationView{
        func loadImage()  {
            guard let selectedImage = selectedImage else {
                return
            }
            image = Image(uiImage: selectedImage)
            
        }
    }
    //
    struct RegistrationView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        
        static var previews: some View {
            RegistrationView()
        }
    }
```

[this is my issue when I tap on country code to choose the country code you will see the button sign in over countries code list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNTno.png)
you also can check from  [here]:**github.com/PhanithNoch/SwiftUIPhoneTextField** this is the repo that I tried to separate code from my real project as an example
I stuck with this a few days ago hope anyone can help, please.

Comment: Can you make a [mre] that someone can copy and paste into Xcode and test? If not, it's unlikely that it'll be debuggable.

Comment: thanks for replying sir, https://github.com/PhanithNoch/SwiftUIPhoneTextField this is the repo that I tried to separate code from my real project as an example

Comment: Is that really the smallest amount of code necessary to present the issue? It's a lot for someone to dig through.

Comment: yeah that's necessary code that we should debug

Comment: I'd be willing to bet that there's a lot in there that you could remove and still get the layout issue that you're experiencing. It's a good exercise in the debugging process anyway, to find out what is a culprit and what has no effect.

Comment: As @jnpdx said you should create a minimal reproducible example. The repo that you linked is your entire project... it would be much easier to find the problem if you isolated it.

Comment: yeah anyway thanks for joining and give some ideas but let me try to check it again but one more thing before I decide to ask in here I got stuck a week ago if anyone can know what happed please tell me also

Comment: thank all of you now my problem it's solved after debugging 4 hours ago